# Web Scraping Google Finance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to teach myself how to web scrape stock data. I'm quite a newbie so please excuse any stupid questions I may ask.

Here's my code for scraping the price and I'm trying to scrape the PE ratio as well.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start = 'http://www.google.com/finance?cid=694653'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(start)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
          

P = soup.find('span',{'id':'ref_694653_l'})

print(P.get_text())

                     
pe = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'val'})

print(pe[5].get_text())

pe = soup.find('td',{'data-snapfield':'pe_ratio'})

print(pe.td.next_sibling.get_text())
```

I can get the price data, and i managed to get the PE ratio but not directly. I tried to use `next_sibling` and `next_element` but it gives me an error saying there is no attribute.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to scrape data from a table as it's usually set up in rows and the classes around the data are usually very common like `<td>` or `<tr>`.

So just wanted to ask for some help in scraping the PE ratio.

Thanks guys

YS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

```
>>> pe = soup.find('td',{'data-snapfield':'pe_ratio'})
>>> pe
<td class="key" data-snapfield="pe_ratio">P/E
</td>
>>> print(pe.td.next_sibling.get_text())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> pe
<td class="key" data-snapfield="pe_ratio">P/E
</td>
>>> pe.td
>>> pe.next_sibling
u'\n'
>>> pe.next_sibling.next_sibling
<td class="val">29.69
</td>
>>> pe.next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text()
u'29.69\n'
```

Comment: Thanks Karan! If I understand correctly then, was my mistake because in the pe variable, the tag was already included so putting pe.td.next_sibling.next_sibling is wrong as the td is extra?

Comment: Yes exactly. If the answer was helpful, please upvote it. If it answered your question, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `cid=694653` was a ticket id back then, currently there's no P/E rating data on the following URL: `http://www.google.com/finance?cid=694653`, you'll get to the main page instead.

Currently, to get specific data you would go to such URL: `https://www.google.com/finance/quote/GOOGL:NASDAQ` where `GOOGL:NASDAQ` is a ticket name.

---

To get all data including p/e ratio data you need to iterate over each key and value:

[image]

```py
right_panel_keys = soup.select(".gyFHrc .mfs7Fc")   # select every key
right_panel_values = soup.select(".gyFHrc .P6K39c") # select every value

for key, value in zip_longest(right_panel_keys, right_panel_values):
    # key is your key -> previous close
    # value is your value -> $2,803.01
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/web-scraping-from-google-finance-returned-data-list-always-e#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest
from itertools import zip_longest


def scrape_google_finance(ticker: str):
    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
    params = {
        "hl": "en"  # langugae
        }

    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
    # https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
        }

    html = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{ticket}", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
    right_panel_data = {"right_panel": {}}
    
    right_panel_keys = soup.select(".gyFHrc .mfs7Fc")
    right_panel_values = soup.select(".gyFHrc .P6K39c")
    
    for key, value in zip_longest(right_panel_keys, right_panel_values):
        key_value = key.text.lower().replace(" ", "_")

        right_panel_data["right_panel"][key_value] = value.text
    
    return right_panel_data
    

data = scrape_google_finance(ticker="GOOGL:NASDAQ")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))                    # prints full output

print(data["right_panel"].keys())                    # show available keys
print(data["right_panel"].get("p/e_ratio"))          # get p/e ratio value
```

Outputs:

```json
{
  "right_panel": {
    "previous_close": "$2,803.01",
    "day_range": "$2,806.21 - $2,874.24",
    "year_range": "$2,091.43 - $3,030.93",
    "market_cap": "1.89T USD",
    "volume": "1.68M",
    "p/e_ratio": "25.49",
    "dividend_yield": "-",
    "primary_exchange": "NASDAQ",
    "ceo": "Sundar Pichai",
    "founded": "Oct 2, 2015",
    "headquarters": "Mountain View, CaliforniaUnited States",
    "website": "abc.xyz",
    "employees": "156,500"
  }
}
```

```
dict_keys(['previous_close', 'day_range', 'year_range', 'market_cap', 'volume', 'p/e_ratio', 'dividend_yield', 'primary_exchange', 'ceo', 'founded', 'headquarters', 'website', 'employees'])
```

```
25.49
```

If you want to scrape more data with a line-by-line explanation, there's a [Scrape Google Finance Ticker Quote Data in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-finance-ticker-quote-data-in-python/#what_will_be_scraped) blog post of mine.